# stop event from bubbling up the DOM

Tags: jquery, events, event-propagation

I have an event handler that is being fired on a container document, propagating it to a li-Element down inside itself. For some reason, when I press return, the event also fires for a link a bit further up the DOM tree. I wasn't able to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM and I don't know why. Can anyone help? Thanks.

I'm using jQuery 1.7 and unfortunately I can't give live code examples that make any sense due to the complexity of it... :-(

My HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="contentBox">

    <form [...]>

        <a class="del" href="javascript:[...]">Delete entry</a>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>An entry</legend>

            <input name="xy" class="lmti">

            <ul>
                <li>Result 1</li>
                <li>Result 2</li>
                <li>Result ...</li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>
```

Pieces of my Javascript look like this:

```
$('#contentBox').on('click', '.del', function(e) { [...deletes an entry...] });
```

and

```
$('#contentBox').on('keyup', '.lmti', function (e) { [...takes over search results...] });
```

What happens is this:

Contents of *#contentBox* are dynamically loaded using ajax.
I have a list of elements in there, which I can dynamicly expand.
Each time I add a new element, a set of all tags within a *fieldset* is being added.
I can delete an element using the link *class="del"* next to it.
When a user types into the input box I dispay a live-search-box below it, so he can take over entries from there. This can also be done by pressing *arrow down*, going through the search results and then pressing *return* to take over a result.

Within above event I check for a pressed *return* and I actually take a title from a list of titles and put it in a HTML-input field. Like the google live search.

The problem: if I press *return* to take over a result set the above event is also being fired for the click-event-handler of the delete-link.

I wasn't able to stop propagation with any combination of *e.stopPropagation*, *e.stopImmediatePropagation*, *e.preventDefault()* and so on.

I only found that checking the event-target within the delete-link event-handler stops the entry from being deleted. But I'd prefer the event not to reach the *a*-click event.

%-/

Any ideas?

Comment: The event handlers you've bound using `on` will only fire if the element they occur within matches the given selector. As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WUYvp/), the reduced example you've given works perfectly. **I'd check the HTML you've got is valid, and you're closing tags in the correct order, and haven't missed a closing tag.** If you continue to have problems, the only way we can help is if you can provide a snippet of code which displays the behaviour your experiencing.

Comment: Examine the `e.target` property - it will tell you at which element the event fired.

Comment: @Matt "*The event handlers ... will only fire ...*". Events **fire** at elements, event handlers are **executed** (or invoked) as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using jQuery's `event.stopPropagation();`?

try using this:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

along with:

```
event.bubbles = false;
```

works like a charm.....

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.new-projects-edit-show', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

> This worked for me.

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: It is shown form the code that it will stop bubble up behavior as the answer should be precise.